# How do we link wires in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

I used name tool.

I clicked #7 for the left and named CS and then i clicked #3 for the right and named CS

[image]

They should be the same after the connect each other question . However the gray are like in this picture didn't occur.

[image]

Did i do right? if yes, how do i see our connected pins if they are connected?

Comment: As an addition to the answer: You can "show" that pins are connected by using the "show" command. Either click on the "eye-symbol" on the toolbar and than on a net element or type "show NETNAME" ("show CS" for example) in the command box to highlight all connected net elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey element holding the net name is called a "label". Use the label command and click on the wire. A floating text element with the net name will show up, place it down with another left click. To make it show up in a little tag-like geometry, right-click it and enable its XRef property.

Comment: @ucha: Note that you don't HAVE to place the labels to create a connection between net elements. Its just a cosmetic thing.

Comment: @Rev1.0 yes, once you name both wires with the same net name, they are considered connected